# Как сделать таймер на скринсейвер?

Tags: delphi

Здравствуйте, подскажите как сделать, чтобы через, например, 10 мин включался скринсейвер, написанный на дельфи.

З.Ы. Скринсейвер есть, осталось поставить время через которое он включался бы.
Заранее спасибо.

Answer (score 3):

Переименуй его exe в SCR и кинь в папку с виндой.
Система его сама подхватит и будет запускать по истечению времени

Comment: не все так просто, программа должна учитывать входящие параметры или что то в таком духе. А система уже действительно его сама будет запускать

Comment: Написание хранителя экрана: [Написание хранителя экрана](http://delphiworld.narod.ru/base/create_ss.html)